# Sending user to their current url location? How?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation, twitter-bootstrap, action, modal-dialog

I am using twitter bootstrap and have a fixed nav bar. The navbar has a button which launches a modal prompting for user input. Once done the user presses "send btn". Because of how my modal is written, it sends the user to another location on my website.

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "home", :action => "send_maill") do %>
```

I want the user to go back to their current location once the user presses "send".

Comment: BTW you have a typo in your action.. should be `send_mail`, not `send_maill`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
def send_mail
  # do your stuff
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: I dont know how... I try to up-vote it... but it wont let me as i dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding AJAX to your form. You can do this by adding `:remote => true` to your form_tag. The action will then be hit by AJAX. You can then perhaps add a notice into the controller.

`flash.now[:notice] = 'Congratulations, your mail has been sent`

and in send_mail.js.erb the flash notification can be shown via the following javascript. You might have to change the ids and class as to your implementation.

```
$("#notice").html("<%= escape_javascript(flash.now[:notice]) %>");
$(".flashes").fadeIn();
```